# How to use Two border color using CSS

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I'm not good at English. Sorry T.T;;

I want to make a box [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwAPr.jpg), which has a border with two colors. I've been trying to make it using CSS `border-color`, but I cannot implement it. I hope to know any idea for this.

I do not want to have a duplicated `div`.  I want to use CSS only.

How can I design this using CSS ? pls T.T;;

This is what I have so far:

```css
#box{
 margin-top:10px;
 width: 950px;
 height:100px;
 border:5px solid #f3f3f3;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

</div>
```

[Regards,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXPCZ.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the CSS3 [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

```css
#box{
margin-top:10px;
width: 950px;
height:100px;
border:5px solid #f3f3f3;
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

When you apply the `box-shadow` with a `0px` value for the x-offset and y-offset, you get the shadow on all four sides.  Furthermore with a `0px` value for the blur, it ultimately looks like a border with two colors.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)